# Javascript Table from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I've created a simple function to return a table from a json object. I'm sure that my code can be improved so that the first line isn't required to be blank and wondered if someone could help with this.

My function does not require jQuery and I would prefer to use native javascript for this implementation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON Table</title>
<script>
function JSONtable(j,r){
    // requirement: first record should be blank
    var v = [];
    var k = [];
    var iv = [];
    var ik = [];
    var iiv = [];
    var iik = [];
    var t = '';
    var f = 0;
    var fi = 0;
    for (k in j) {
        if (k==r){
            t = '<table name="'+k+'">';
            v = j[k];
            for (ik in j[k]) {
                t = t+'<tr>';
                for (iik in j[k][ik]) {
                    if (f==0){
                        t = t+'<th>'+iik+'</th>';
                    }else{
                        t = t+'<td>'+j[k][ik][iik]+'</td>';
                    }
                    fi++;
                }
                f++;
                t = t+'</tr>';
            }
            t = t+'</table>';
        }
    }
    return t;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var j = {"employees":[{"firstName":"-blank-", "lastName":"-blank-", "link":"-blank-"},{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"}]};
document.write(JSONtable(j,'employees'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

```
<table name="employees">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>firstName</th>
            <th>lastName</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anna</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Jones</td>
            <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**New code that does not require a blank record**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON Table</title>
<script>
function JSONtable(j,r){
    var v = [];
    var k = [];
    var iv = [];
    var ik = [];
    var iiv = [];
    var iik = [];
    var t = '';
    var f = 0;
    for (k in j) {
        if (k==r){
            t = '<table name="'+k+'">';
            t = t+'<tr>';
            for (i of Object.keys(j[k][0])) {
                t = t+'<th>'+i+'</th>';
            }
            t = t+'</tr>';
            v = j[k];
            for (ik in j[k]) {
                t = t+'<tr>';
                for (iik in j[k][ik]) {
                    t = t+'<td>'+j[k][ik][iik]+'</td>';
                }
                f++;
                t = t+'</tr>';
            }
            t = t+'</table>';
        }
    }
    return t;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var j = {"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"}]};
document.write(JSONtable(j,'employees'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there actually a problem with your code? If not, Stack Overflow is not the right place to get feedback for your code.

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want your code reviewed

Comment: the problem was clearly stated.. his function requires the first row to be blank he can't figure out how to do it without this requirement. gosh ppl are so picky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` to get the names of the array keys and build the headers first. Then cycle through the rest of the list.

```
<title>JSON Table</title>
<script>
function JSONtable(j,r){
    // requirement: first record should be blank
    var v = [];
    var k = Object.keys(j)[0];
    var iv = [];
    var ik = [];
    var iiv = [];
    var iik = [];
    var t = '';
    var f = 0;
    var fi = 0;

    if (k === r) {
        t = '<table name="'+k+'">';
        t = t+'<tr>';
        for (i of Object.keys(j[k][0])) {
            t = t+'<th>'+i+'</th>';
        }
        t = t+'</tr>';

        for (k in j) {
            v = j[k];
            for (ik in j[k]) {
                t = t+'<tr>';
                for (iik in j[k][ik]) {
                    t = t+'<td>'+j[k][ik][iik]+'</td>';
                    fi++;
                }
                f++;
                t = t+'</tr>';
           }

        }
        t = t+'</table>';
    }
    return t;
}
</script>
<body>
<script>
    var j = {"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "link":"<a href=\"#\">Link</a>"}]};
    document.write(JSONtable(j,'employees'));
</script>
```